# SimpleExcel class not Parsing csv file correct

Tags: php, csv

I am using SimpleExcel class for parsing the CSV file in php.In this csv file has bluk data with comma, spaces and enter when class parse the csv file and create object it retrun wrong array(one row divided into more then one row)

```
$excel = new SimpleExcel('CSV');
$excel->parser->loadFile($fileName, 'CSV');
for ($i = 1; $i < $read; $i++) 
{
    $this->object[] = $excel->parser->getRow($i);
}
```

the '$this->object' object return wrong array
Sample CSV :

- The standard,Lorem Ipsum passage,used since the 1500s
- The standard, Lorem ,Ipsum, passage, used ,since ,the, 1500s

> Blockquote

```
[28] => Array
    (
        [0] => the
        [1] =>  standard
        [2] =>  Lorem
        [3] =>  Ipsum 

    )

[29] => Array
    (
        [0] => passage
        [1] => used since the 1500s
        [2] => 
        [3] => 

    )
```

29 array has contain value of 28 array.actually this is one array which is divided into two different array

```
I want array like that
[28] => Array
    (
        [0] => The standard
        [1] =>  Lorem Ipsum passage
        [2] =>  used since the 1500s
    )

[29] => Array
    (
        [0] => The standard
        [1] => Lorem Ipsum
        [2] => passage
        [3] => used since the 1500s
    )
```

Comment: Does any of the csv entries have a newline character? Show the relevant part of the CSV file that you have, and what you expect to see in the array

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$excel->parser->loadFile(
    $fileName, 
    'CSV', 
    array(
        'delimiter' => ','
    )
);
```

to force usage of a comma delimiter;

or fix the library code:

line 78 of the CSVParser should read:

```
$args  = str_getcsv($line, $sep);
```

rather than

```
$args  = str_getcsv($sep, $line);
```

Comment: the above changes are not work their is same issue please give another solution .
i have bulk data in CSV file which contain long string , one cell has long string including with comma and enter .when library read this one cell it divided this cell into multiple cells, that is issue .I want one cell should be one cell not a library chnage into multiple cells

Comment: I've already told you what the problem is, and fixed one bug for you in that library... but I'd suggest if that doesn't help, you might be better using the standard fgetcsv() function to read the file

Comment: there is 3 cells in CSV file like this:
cell1   cell2    cell3
like this i have many infomation in csv file ,in that file cell 3 has long strings where some string save with enter '/r'. Line no.58 of the CSVParse has used $pattern = "/\r\n|\n|\r/"; . when this library read cell3 and found enter '/r' it create new row (object). i want it ignore the enter '/r' in cell3 .after read full cell3 then it go to next row..
i have no option to use another library.please give me a solution ASAP.